# Deserialize a restful uri

Tags: c#, rest, serialization, service

I'm trying to deserialize a rest uri located at http://ws.geonames.org/countryInfo?lang=it&country=DE and keep getting error (There is an error in XML document (1, 1)). Plug http://ws.geonames.org/countryInfo?lang=it&country=DE into the browser and you can see the result.

I have a class

```
public class Country
{
    public string CountryName {get;set;}
    public string CountryCode {get;set;}
}
```

and the method in my console app is as follows:

```
   static void DeserializeTheXML()
    {

        XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
        xRoot.ElementName = "countryName";
        xRoot.IsNullable = true;


        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Country), xRoot);
        XmlReader xRdr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader("http://ws.geonames.org/countryInfo?lang=it&country=DE"));
        Country tvd = new Country();
        tvd = (Country)ser.Deserialize(xRdr);



        Console.WriteLine("Country Name = " + tvd.CountryName);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

any ideas on how to deserialize this rest service? thanks..

Comment: In addition to Darin's answer: your string reader does not fetch the XML from the web service, but simply contains your URL as a string, which will lead to an XML deserialization error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For serialization to work successfully you need to decorate your objects with the proper serialization attributes or use the XmlAttributeOverrides constructor. Also don't forget that XML is case sensitive and your objects must reflect the XML structure you are deserializing:

```
public class GeoNames
{
    [XmlElement("country")]
    public Country[] Countries { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    [XmlElement("countryName")]
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("countryCode")]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
} 

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var url = "http://ws.geonames.org/countryInfo?lang=it&country=DE";
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GeoNames), new XmlRootAttribute("geonames"));
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        using (var stream = client.OpenRead(url))
        {
            var geoNames = (GeoNames)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
            foreach (var country in geoNames.Countries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "code: {0}, name: {1}", 
                    country.CountryCode, 
                    country.CountryName
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to remove a namespace from the example above? tried this on another rest uri and it contains a namespace. thanks..

Comment: - <ArrayOfFoodTruck xmlns="Artybones" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
- <FoodTruck>
  <Company i:nil="true" /> 
  <DayOfWeek i:nil="true" /> 
  <Location i:nil="true" /> 
  <TimeOfDay i:nil="true" /> 
  <TruckID>0</TruckID> 
  <TruckName>BBQ Smith</TruckName> 
  <Website>http://www.bbqsmith.com</Website> 
  </FoodTruck>

Comment: Please don't use the comments section to post code snippets. It is completely unreadable. Either update your original question or start a new thread as from what I can see that's a very different structure than the one you initially asked here.